# MacBook (13-inch, Late 2009) only boots up to Apple logo with little spinning wheel

Tags: single-user

Using single-user mode, I get this message:

> launchctl: Please convert the following to launchd: /etc/mach_init.d/dashboardadvisory.plist

What does it mean and how do I convert launchctl to launchd?

Comment: Did you attempt to install/upgrade macOS recently?

Answer (score 1):

This is your one and only hope that I know of.

**Login Single User Mode and to repair a disk**

Boot the Mac into Single User Mode by holding down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> during system boot. After you hear the boot chime, you know you will have successfully entered Single User Mode because you will see a bunch of white text on a black background scroll by.

When the Single User boot sequence has finished, you’ll find a small command prompt at the bottom of the screen prefixed by a hash sign (#), when you see that type the following command exactly:

```
fsck -fy
```

Once fsck completes, if you see a “File system was modified” message, then you should run “`fsck -fy`” again until you see a message stating “The volume (name) appears to be OK” – this is standard procedure of using fsck.

Type “reboot” to leave Single User Mode and boot the Mac back into OS X as usual.
Once OS X is booted again, it can be a good idea to confirm all is well by going back to Disk Utility and running the “Verify” tool to check on the drive's health.

**If the above does not work**

I hate to share this with you, but I have never seen a fix for this, other than connect the drive to another Mac and recover any files you can access at this point.

95% chance a reformat is the only solution.

Try to save what you can and hopefully there are no important files on the drive.